# WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 compatibility

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB 1.5.2 , AS 1.5.2 and DSS 1.5.2 on our middleware. All of these products get username information from shared database. We would like to upgrade our ESB from Stratos 1.5.2 to ESB 4.5.1. When i install new ESB it is going to create new username with tenant id -1234. Do you think it will affect to use these three different product version on same environment.

ps : As far as i saw super tenant id has been changed from 0 to -1234 on new products. Because of this it is creating new username on DB. Do you have any reason to change super tenant id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Stratos 1.5.2 and WSO2 Stratos 1.6 (ESB 4.5.1) are NOT backward compatible. If you want to migrate form 1.5.2 to 1.6 based platform, you need to do a data migration.

The reason for changing from 0 to -1234 is a design decision made to avoid possible mix-up with super tenant and other tenants.